# Segue двойной переход

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь реализовать переход с передачей переменной на ViewController при нажатии на ячейку таблицы, но при нажатии переходит не передавая перевенную, а следом осуществляется переход уже с переданной переменной. Т.е. появляется лишнее звено в навигации.
Здесь передаю переменую:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTaskViewController
    controller.taskID = self.IDForDT 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! TaskListTableViewCell
    self.IDForDT = currentCell.TaskListID.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SHOWDT", sender: self)
}
```

Здесь эта переменная обрабатывается:

```
class DetailTaskViewController: UIViewController {
var detailtask = [DetailTask?]()
var taskID: String?


@IBOutlet weak var DetailTaskName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailTaskImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailTaskDescr: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailTaskURL: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    loadTaskList(self.taskID)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.taskID)

}  //...
```

print(self.taskID) сначала возвращает nil, а после уже переданные данные.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно это исправить?

Comment: У Вас в storyboard segue ведёт от ячейки к DetailTaskViewController ? Вот он и отрабатывает передавая nil. Следом уже срабатывает Ваш программный.

Comment: а как это можно исправить?

Comment: shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier - тут проверяете наличие нужных параметров. Если есть, разрешаете переход.

Answer (score 1):

Первый переход вызывает segue идущий от ячейки таблицы.
Второй переход вызываете вы командой performSegueWithIdentifier.
Удалите storyboard segue идущий от ячейки таблицы и добавьте новый (с тем же именем "SHOWDT") от самого uiviewcontroller. Для добавления выберите масштаб отображения, например 50% и перетяните segue от одного uiviewcontroller ко второму. Это создат segue, не привязанный к конкретному элементу, который вы вызовете через команду performSegueWithIdentifier("SHOWDT", sender: self).